# Why does "await LoadAsync()" freeze the UI while "await Task.Run(() => Load())" does not?

Tags: .net, wpf, entity-framework, async-await

I'm following [a walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574514.aspx) on how to combine EntityFramework with WPF. I decided to play around with async/await while I'm at it, because I've never really had a chance to use it before (we've just moved to VS2013/.NET 4.5 from VS2010/.NET 4.0). Getting the save button handler to be async was a breeze, and the UI remained responsive (I can drag the window around) while SaveChangesAsync() is awaited. In the window load handler, however, I ran into a small snag.

```
    private async void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        EnterBusyState();
        var categoryViewSource = (CollectionViewSource)FindResource("categoryViewSource");
        _context = await Task.Run(() => new Context());
        await Task.Run(() => _context.Categories.Load());
        //await _context.Categories.LoadAsync();
        categoryViewSource.Source = _context.Categories.Local;
        LeaveBusyState();
    }
```

When I use the first way of loading _context.Categories, the UI remains responsive, but when I substitute with the commented-out line below, the UI freezes for a brief moment while the entities load. Does anyone have an explanation on why the former works while the latter doesn't? It's not a big deal, it's just bugging me that the second line doesn't work when, at least according to what I've researched about async/await so far, it should.

Answer (score 7):

Even if a method ends with `*Async` or return a Task does not mean it is fully async or async at all...

Example:

```
public Task FooAsync()
{
    Thread.Sleep(10000); // This blocks the calling thread
    return Task.FromResult(true);
}
```

Usage (looks like an async call):

```
await FooAsync();
```

The sample method is completely synchronous even though it returns a task... You need to check the implementation of `LoadAsync` and ensure that nothing blocks.

When using `Task.Run` everything in the lambda is executed async on the thread pool... (or at least not blocking the calling thread).

Comment: As written, when compiled `FooAsync()` will generate warning [CS1998](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13243975/1497596): *"This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread."*