# How to make asynchronous methods that use a queue thread safe

Tags: c#, .net, thread-safety, async-await

I have a service that ensures that exactly one popup is displayed at the same time. `AddPopupAsync` can be called concurrently, i.e. a popup is open while another 10 `AddPopupAsync` requests drop in. The code:

```
public async Task<int> AddPopupAsync(Message message)
{
    //[...]

    while (popupQueue.Count != 0)
    {
        await popupQueue.Peek();
    }

    return await Popup(interaction);
}
```

But I can spot two unwanted things that can happen because of the **lack of thread safety**:

1. If the queue is empty, Peek will throw an exception
2. If a thread A is preempted before the first statement in Popup, another thread B will not wait for the pending popup A since the queue is still empty.

Popup method works with a `TaskCompletionSource` and before calling its `SetResult` method, `popupQueue.Dequeue()` is called.

I think about using the atomic `TryPeek` from `ConcurrentQueue` in order to make #1 thread safe:

```
do
{
    Task<int> result;

    bool success = popupQueue.TryPeek(out result);

    if (!success) break;
    await result;
} 
while (true);
```

Then I read about a [AsyncProducerConsumerCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873173(v=vs.110).aspx) but I'm not sure if that is the most simple solution.

How can I ensure thread safety in a simple way? Thank you.

Comment: I think you've answered your own question. `ConcurrentQueue<T>` has what you need built-in.

Comment: Your current semantics are that all calls to `AddPopupAsync` will not complete until all popups are shown (not just the one that that particular call is showing). Are you sure that's the semantics you want?

Comment: @Stephen Cleary Since PopupView and PopupViewModel are singletons, the state of the modal popup window is changed whenever Popup is called. And that is why I'm using a queue.

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to treat this UI-service-like-thing as though it were part of the UI; i.e., only call `AddPopupAsync` from the UI context?

Comment: @Stephen Cleary: If AddPopupAsync is only called from the UI thread, AddPopupAsync runs on a worker thread because of the await keyword. Right? Do you want to say that there is no need for asynchronous functions since there is no compute-bound work in AddPopupAsync and if there aren't asynchronous functions any longer, the code will be thread safe?

Comment: `await` does not introduce worker threads. Unless you're calling `AddPopupAsync` from *other threads*, it doesn't need to be threadsafe. For more about how `async` works, check out my [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

Comment: Just FYI: Its up to the AddPopupAsync how async is implemented or implemented at all, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27051169/why-does-await-loadasync-freeze-the-ui-while-await-task-run-load/27071434#27071434

Answer (score 8):

To simply add thread-safety you should use a `ConcurrentQueue`. It's a thread-safe implementation of a queue and you can use it just the same way you would use a queue without worrying about concurrency.

However if you want a queue you can `await` asynchronously (which means that you're not busy-waiting or blocking a thread while waiting) you should use TPL Dataflow's `BufferBlock` which is very similar to `AsyncProducerConsumerCollection` only already implemented for you by MS:

```
var buffer = new BufferBlock<int>();
await buffer.SendAsync(3); // Instead of enqueue.
int item = await buffer.ReceiveAsync(); // instead of dequeue.
```

`ConcurrentQueue` is fine for thread-safeness, but wasteful in high levels of contention. `BufferBlock` is not only thread-safe it also gives you asynchronous coordination (usually between a consumer and producer).

Comment: But ConcurrentQueue doesn't indicate that the code using ConcurrentQueue is thread safe, does it (see #2 in my question)?

Comment: @user4287276 `ConcurrentQueue` makes sure each call to one of its methods is thread-safe by itself. It's not a locking mechanism. If you need synchronization in your code you should use a `lock` (or `AsyncLock` if its appropriate).

Comment: BufferBlock doesn't have a peek method

Comment: @ArnoldPistorius does it have a `TryReceive` method that accepts a predicate that can be used as a "peek"?