# Does "async" run in a separate thread?

Tags: c#, task

When I call to foo(), is this method runs on a separate thread?

```
public async Task<bool> foo(){
  //Some code 
}
```

Comment: No. [There is no thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)

Comment: Please take a look at the following [post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37419572/if-async-await-doesnt-create-any-additional-threads-then-how-does-it-make-appl)

Comment: Depending on the current's thread _SynchronizationContext_ and what you do inside that method, especially what other async calls you are awaiting and if you're awaiting them with `.ConfigureAwait(false)`, it might be possible that the method is _resumed_ on a different thread (after an await) , but it starts to run on the caller's thread synchronously.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, it does not. It MAY start another thread internally and return that task, but the general idea is that it does not run on any thread.

Let me explain. The general use of async is if you are not CPU bound and that means IO and all IO in windows has callback operated interfaces at the lowest level, so - a network request sends the request and then goes on with work - but there is no thread attached. At all. The general use case for async is that async runs on a thread and when nothing is there to do it will then use the threads for the tasks completed, allowing multiple operations on one thread - AND... the IO will not use up a thread.

Your method basically turns into a state engine relinquishing control to the task scheduler waiting for a completed task being signalled.

Answer (score 3):

Making the method with `async` don't mean that it will create another thread. If the `CLR` is seeing that your *method* which is called with `await` in your `async` method is delayed, it is exiting from that method and waits after awaited methods finish and then continue that method with another thread.

When you invoke a method marked as `async`, it begins running synchronously on the current thread.

So, the conclusion is that `async` doesn't create it's own `thread`. The *thread* of the calling method is used to execute the `async` method till it finds an *awaitable*. The same thread then continues to execute the rest of the calling method beyond the `async` method call. Within the called `async` method, after returning from the awaitable, the continuation can be executed on a thread from the *thread pool*, the only place a separate thread comes into picture.

Answer (score 1):

No, the tasks do not imply that there is a separate thread that runs.  In the case where your task needs to block on another async task within its method body, it can return execution temporarily while the blocked resource is being waited for, and then returns execution back to complete the task.  This is basically what the `await` keyword is used for.  A typical async task is one that waits on I/O or networking resources to return data after a true asynchronous operation has begun.  It is also possible that your method itself spawns its own thread, making it asynchronous, but it really just depends on the implementation of the async method itself.

A great explanation is found on this page, in the "cooking breakfast analogy":
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/

Note that it is possible to run tasks in parallel, which can spawn separate threads, but when you just call the methods directly, that is not done by default.