# Need some explanations about async/await and thread safety

Tags: c#, async-await

Yet another question about thread safety and async/await.
I don't understand why my second increment is not thread safe.

```
class Program
{
    static int totalCountB = 0; 
    static int totalCountA = 0;
    
    static async Task AnotherTask()
    {
        totalCountA++; // Thread safe
        await Task.Delay(1);
        totalCountB++; // not thread safe 
    }

    static async Task SpawnManyTasks(int taskCount)
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(Enumerable.Range(0, taskCount)
            .Select(_ => AnotherTask()));
    }

    static async Task Main()
    {
        await SpawnManyTasks(10_000);

        Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(totalCountA)} : " + totalCountA); // Output 10000
        Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(totalCountB)} : " + totalCountB); // Output 9856
    }
}
```

What I understand :

- `totalCountA++` is thread safe because, until that point, the code is completely sync.
- I understand that `await` may be run on the threadpool, but  I didn't expect that the code resuming the `await` will be completely multi-threaded.

According to the some answers/blogs, async/await should not create a new thread :

- [Does the use of async/await create a new thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27265818/does-the-use-of-async-await-create-a-new-thread)
- https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html

I'm really missing something big here.

Comment: `await ...` may not be creating a thread, but continuation needs to run somewhere and it  easily can be another thread.

Comment: In short, if you are dealing with tasks or threads, and you are have shared resources, you will need thread safety, yes there are a lot of substiles and a lot of ways to minimizing thread safety techniques, and write no lock code. However, its kind of link bragging about you only needing one sheet of toilet paper..  Unless you fully understand all code paths and how tasks and the async and await pattern works just lock the shared resource and be done with it...

Comment: Read about SynchronizationContext. Run this code within a WinForms application from the MainThread context and after `await` you will be back in the MainThread context again (because of the special SynchronizationContext of WinForms applications)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> totalCountA++ is thread safe because, until that point, the code is completely sync.

Yes. This is because [`async` methods begin executing on the calling thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html), just like synchronous methods (attribution: me).

> I understand that await may be run on the threadpool, but I didn't expect that the code resuming the await will be completely multi-threaded.

The `await` doesn't "run" anywhere. That's the point of my There Is No Thread article you linked to.

Now, *after* the `await`, the rest of the code needs to run somewhere. `await` by default will [capture a "context" and use that to execute the remainder of the `async` method](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) (attribution: me). That "context" is `SynchronizationContext.Current`, unless it is `null`, in which case it is `TaskScheduler.Current`. In a Console application, this means that the context is the thread pool context, so *any available thread pool thread* will execute the remainder of the `async` method.

Answer (score 3):

> totalCountA++ is thread safe because, until that point, the code is completely sync.

Yes, that is correct.

> I understand that await may be run on the threadpool, but I didn't expect that the code resuming the await will be completely multi-threaded.

Well, the code after the `await` is not multi-threaded per se. The code after the `await`, in this case the `totalCountB++` operation, will run in *some* thread. Which thread picks it up depends on many factors and cannot be relied upon when there is no `SynchronizationContext`.

Think of this case:

1. First iteration runs up to `await`.
2. Second iteration runs up to `await`.
3. Some thread (a) resumes the code of the first iteration, and reads `totalCountB=0`
4. Another thread (b) resumes the code and reads `totalCountB=0`
5. Thread a assigns `totalCountB=1`
6. Thread b assigns `totalCountB=1`

It can also happen that thread a finishes before thread b gets started, or even for the same thread a to pick up the next iteration.

Answer (score 2):

What Stephen Cleary is talking about in “There is no thread” is that you do not need to occupy a thread while waiting for async IO to complete.

Your claim “await may be run on the threadpool” doesn’t make sense. Await doesn’t run anywhere, it suspends execution until the task is complete.

Rather, it is true that in some execution models, the code after the await may be run on a threadpool thread.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t have the reference in front of me, but lack of a synchronization  context in a console application dramatically alters the behavior. There are much fewer guarantees as to which thread your code will run on.

If you run the same thing in a WPF application, you should find that it behaves more how you expect.