# Is static async Task<T> method is thread safety by default?

Tags: .net, async-await

The method with signature static async Task is thread safety by default? In general, I assumed that the compiler might create some wrapper that provides "thread-safety". By the way, not on purpose.

Doesn't the compiler seeing 'static async' create something similar to what happens with java compilers and the 'synchronized' keyword?

Sorry for My English.

Comment: No and isn't even asynchronous by default. `async` is syntactic sugar that tells the compiler to create the state machine needed to *await* the execution of already active asynchronous operations. The code inside the method will be able to `await` asynchronous calls without blocking, and get back to the original synchronization context after they complete

Comment: Why this question? What's the actual problem you want to solve? `async/await` simplify writing thread-safe *asynchronous* code. That doesn't mean using multiple threads. In IO and network operations, the code is waiting for either the OS or a remote server to respond. `var text=await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);` awaits for an HTTP response without blocking the current thread, and returns to the original synchronization context afterwards. In a desktop app that would be the UI thread, allowing you to update the UI right after the async call

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It was a question of pure curiosity. I didn't know how the compiler played around with async-await.

Comment: Why did you assume `async` would make a method thread-safe? It means you have a mental model of how it should work already.  Did you expect it to work like JavaScript's `await` perhaps, which actually *starts* a method? Asynchronous doesn't mean parallel or concurrent.

Comment: No, the compiler does nothing like Java. The very names are opposites. `**sync**hronized` vs `**async*hronous`. Again, why the question? You're trying to fit `async/await` to an existing mental model that's simply wrong. Asynchronous programming isn't about threads and synchronization at all. The closest equivalent are callbacks executed after some action completes.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: The situation with static async is more complicated. It's really a matter of what can  handle the rest of the code after the 'await' keyword: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69995931/need-some-explanations-about-async-await-and-thread-safety

Comment: My experience is that there are a number of people who see the Microsoft docs saying that all `static` method of class XXX are thread-safe and they assume it means all `static` methods of all classes are thread-safe. They are not. If it's in the documentation it's only there for those specific methods. It's not a general rule.

Answer (score 2):

"Thread safety" is a vague and non-specific *category* of things; all that `await` (and all the associated bits) do[es] is setup the code to be suspendable and resumable via a state machine (although there is no guarantee that it will ever actually become truly async - it can run synchronously from start to finish); you need to be more specific

- if you're asking about supporting concurrent invocation: that, just like any other code, depends on shared state (typically fields) and how you interact with them - we can't answer it from here
- if you mean "do I come back on the same thread" (in terms of `[ThreadStatic]` etc): you should assume "no", but it *might* depending on sync-context (although that is an implementation detail of specific sync-context which may or may not be present)
- if you mean "does my single method itself become self-concurrent" - if you `await` results immediately: no; if you don't: "possibly"
- if you mean things like volatility, atomicity, etc: no more or less than any other code, although if you *do* jump threads the impact of these factors may be *exacerbated* - but the same concerns already existed
- if you mean thread-bound locking (`lock` etc): don't ever use that with `await`

there are many other possible interpretations of "thread safety" - so: you'd need to be *very specific*

Comment: I suspect the OP confuses asynchronous and concurrent programming.

Comment: In general, I assumed that the compiler might create some wrapper that provides "thread-safety".

Comment: @user1785960 no, the compiler makes it easier to handle operation completions without callbacks. The `a` in async is a negation. `asynchronous` means `not synchronous`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos
I see that the anwser depends on execution context: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69995931/need-some-explanations-about-async-await-and-thread-safety

Comment: @user1785960 not quite. It's `await` that awaits for an active task to complete without blocking the original thread and returns execution to the original synchronization (not execution) context, after a Task completes. In a desktop application that means getting back to the UI thread. In a web application, where every request is served by a different threadpool thread, it means re-establishing the request context on a different thread. While awaiting, the original thread is free to perform other work

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: In some contexts, we are guaranteed that it will be one exactly the same thread. That's why it's thread-safe.

Comment: @user1785960 again, that comes down to definitions; define "thread safe" - what do you mean by that **exactly** - details matter; you say "same thread" - that is provided only by sync-contexts that *have that as a design feature*, which is *very rare* in modern frameworks, and is *not* an inherent feature of `await`, plus it depends exactly *what* you await; if I `await SomethingAsync().ConfigureAwait(false)`, then: that's gone again; sync-context is *not even remotely* like "synchronized", and attempting to compare them is not a good idea