# Does Task delay create new Thread?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-core

I would like to ask whether the Task.Delay calls Task.Run underneath and it is reason of change of thread id or there is different logic behind it?

```
async Task Main()
{
     Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId); //11
     await Task.Delay(200);
     Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId); //22
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the `Task.Delay` doesn't call the `Task.Run` underneath. It just returns a `Task` that completes after the specified duration, and invokes any [continuations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith) that are attached to it on the [`ThreadPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool). It uses a [`System.Threading.Timer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer) internally. Its implementation looks like this:

```
public class Task
{
    public static Task Delay(int millisecondsDelay)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource();
        _ = new Timer(_ => tcs.SetResult(), null, millisecondsDelay, -1);
        return tcs.Task;
    }
}
```

So when you `await` the `Task.Delay`, the continuation after the `await` runs on the same thread where the `Timer` callback is invoked¹, which happens to be a `ThreadPool` thread.

**Note:** The above implementation is presented as an example. It's not the actual implementation, and it's not guaranteed to work correctly. The `Timer` instance is not stored anywhere, and so it might become garbage collected before the callback is invoked, resulting in a never-completing `Task`.

¹ <sub>Assuming that no [`SynchronizationContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2011/february/msdn-magazine-parallel-computing-it-s-all-about-the-synchronizationcontext) is in place.</sub>