# Async method lacks await operators warning when the await is in a function passed to an async lambda expresion

Tags: c#, asynchronous, lambda, async-await

I have the following async method, which is a simpler wait and retry in case of failures:

```
public async Task RetryAsync(Func<Task> _action, int _ms = 1000, int _counter = 3) {
    while (true) {
        try {
            await _action();
            return; // success!
        }
        catch {
            if (--_counter == 0)
                throw;
            await Task.Delay(_ms);
        }
    }
}
```

To, *in theory*, be called like this:

```
await RetryAsync(async () => {
    _newID = myDBFunction();
}, 300);
```

Since the function passed to the *RetryAsync* method does not contain any *await*, then obviously this gets the warning:

> This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously.
>   Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls,
>   or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.

... and changing the calling code to this fixes the problem:

```
await RetryAsync(async () => {
    await Task.Run(() => _newID = myDBFunction(););
}, 300);
```

Is there any other way to achieve parallelism for this simple case besides using *Task.Run()*?  Any disadvantage you see to the latest code with *Task.Run()* on it?

Comment: Why do you need to pass `async` method, if in reality it's not `async`?

Comment: Because in most cases it will be an async method what it will be passed, plus I do want to achieve parallelism.

Comment: That's fine, you have your `Func<Task>` signature, but the implementation, doesn't have to be `async`. You can as you said, just use `Task.Run` without the `await` and `async` - What's wrong with that?

Comment: @OfirWinegarten, please write how would you make the call OR how would you change the Retry function.

Comment: I would not change the `RetryAsync`, Just remove the `async` and `await`.  `await RetryAsync(() => Task.Run(() => _newID = myDBFunction()), 300);`

Comment: Thanks, makes sense.  Any advantage compared to the code I put initially?

Comment: This is pretty much a duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13243975/suppress-warning-cs1998-this-async-method-lacks-await.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I recommend using [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly). It's widely used, extensively tested, and has native support for asynchronous as well as synchronous usage.

But if you want to keep using your own, you can add a synchronous equivalent:

```
public async Task RetryAsync(Func<Task> _action, int _ms = 1000, int _counter = 3);
public void Retry(Action _action, int _ms = 1000, int _counter = 3);
```

which can be called as such:

```
Retry(() => {
  _newID = myDBFunction();
}, 300);
```

If you want to *always* put synchronous code on a thread pool, you can add an overload for that, to:

```
public async Task RetryAsync(Func<Task> _action, int _ms = 1000, int _counter = 3);
public async Task RetryAsync(Action _action, int _ms = 1000, int _counter = 3) =>
    await RetryAsync(() => Task.Run(_action), _ms, _counter);
```

which can be called as such:

```
await RetryAsync(() => {
    _newID = myDBFunction();
}, 300);
```