# Overriding async method properly in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

I have a base class that defines an abstract method that returns a Task.

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public abstract Task DoSomething();
}
```

I can make a class that implements the abstract method in these two different ways.

```
public class Example1 : BaseClass
{
    public override Task DoSomething()
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

or like this

```
public class Example2 : BaseClass
{
    public override async Task DoSomething()
    {
    }
}
```

Notice that the first returns a completed task, the second includes the async keyword and doesn't have a return statement. Is there any difference between the two?

Comment: In first return type is needed, in second visual studio say `warning CS1998: This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously.` if you does not use any await in that method. More info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13243975/suppress-warning-cs1998-this-async-method-lacks-await

Comment: better explain https://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2014/03/04/be-aware-of-await-lacks-cs1998.aspx

Comment: @daremachine - thank you for your comments. I didn't get the warning but your explanation makes sense.

Comment: The warnings are in build output or if you have method name underlined in VS, get mouse pointer on that. Glad to help.

Comment: I would use the former example. It is clear, simple, and easy to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is significant difference in the code that gets generated. By merely adding the `async` keyword the method gets compiled very differently.

Here's effectively what the compiler produces:

```
public class Example2 : BaseClass
{
    private struct DoSomethingStateMachine : IAsyncStateMachine
    {
        public int _state;

        public AsyncTaskMethodBuilder _builder;

        private void MoveNext()
        {
            try
            {
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                _state = -2;
                _builder.SetException(exception);
                return;
            }
            _state = -2;
            _builder.SetResult();
        }

        void IAsyncStateMachine.MoveNext()
        {
            this.MoveNext();
        }

        private void SetStateMachine(IAsyncStateMachine stateMachine)
        {
            _builder.SetStateMachine(stateMachine);
        }

        void IAsyncStateMachine.SetStateMachine(IAsyncStateMachine stateMachine)
        {
            this.SetStateMachine(stateMachine);
        }
    }

    public override Task DoSomething()
    {
        DoSomethingStateMachine stateMachine = default(DoSomethingStateMachine);
        stateMachine._builder = AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Create();
        stateMachine._state = -1;
        AsyncTaskMethodBuilder _builder = stateMachine._builder;
        _builder.Start(ref stateMachine);
        return stateMachine._builder.Task;
    }
}
```