# Can I use async instead of threading?

Tags: c#, async-await, kestrel-http-server

I have an unending async in a kestrel server.  Is there anything wrong with this:

```
   public static async void infiniteAsync()
            {
                bool keepgoing = true;
    
                // otherwise meaningless await to overcome 
                // "this 'async' method lacks await operators... will run synchronously"
                await Task.Delay(100); 
    
                do
                {
                    // streaming task that will never end;
                }
                while (keepgoing);
            }
}
```

invoked by kestrel server

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseWebSockets();
            infiniteAsync();
}
```

Comment: no its will run without problem and if you want you can use Task type instance of void to more control and if you want you can use [CancellationToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken) for control method life time

Comment: It seems that you can be interested in [background tasks with hosted services in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: Never use `async void`. Also, don’t abuse await Task.Delay just to get a warning away. If you want to run sync code asynchronously use Task.Run. Aside from that if you want to have a background task then do as Guru Strom linked.

Comment: await Task.FromResult(1) is "better" to get rid of the warning

Comment: Related: [Suppress warning CS1998: This async method lacks 'await'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13243975/suppress-warning-cs1998-this-async-method-lacks-await)

Comment: @Charles "await Task.FromResult(1) is "better" to get rid of the warning" - no the best is to use `Task.Run` to have it actually running on an thread-pool-thread from the start, or use `await Task.Yield()`

Answer (score 0):

If you call this code inside the Startup class the operations will be canceled when the server is shutdown (Operation Cancelled Exception). The recommended approach would be to use a Background task.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio