# Remove the async/await warning CS1998, when implementing interface

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, web-applications, .net-5

Suppose I implement an interface where there are two methods: `Create` and `CreateAsync`. The Async method in my case is not really async, and it uses the syncronous `Create` method to return the created object:

```
public Task<GrandeurDTO> CreateAsync()
{
    var dto = Create();
    return Task.FromResult(dto);
}
public GrandeurDTO Create()
{
    var bo = new Grandeur();

    var dto = _mapper.Map<GrandeurDTO>(bo);
    return dto;
}
```

How should I remove the warning

> This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously.
> Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls,
> or 'await Task.Run(CS1998)

knowing I can't rename the method in `Create` (I already have one; cause if not the question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13243975/suppress-warning-cs1998-this-async-method-lacks-await))

[image]

Comment: I only see that warning for methods that are specified `async`, so I'm not sure why you're seeing it. What version of the compiler and code analysis?

Comment: I think you just need to recompile....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is just a case of a tired Visual Studio and 1) a recompile or 2) VS restart will fix the issue.

Comment: Visual Studio Code... hmm